# Parse JSON response object in IE8

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am using [qq uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) for file uploads with Django. It works fine in modern browsers like FF/Chrome. I have also made some progress in making it work more or less properly in IE8. My issue is that when I upload a file and receive a JSON response from server, looks like this:

```
{"success":true,"url":"/media/campaigns/20111118162942_home_cooking_win_01.png"}
```

My code is like this:

```
onComplete:function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    alert(responseJSON['url']);
}
```

And I successfully load `url` attribute in FF/Chrome, but have no luck in IE8. It gets `undefined` value there. I tried different ways but couldn't get actual value.
What can I do about it?

Comment: the code you posted should work. Something else is afoot.

Comment: Works for me in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dHXzN/

Comment: Have you tried `responseJSON.url`?

Comment: I did. I run absolutely the same code in FF and it shows the value. But IE shows undefined.

Comment: _onComplete_ event function is executed for IE8? Try `onComplete:function(id, fileName, responseJSON) { console.info(1); console.info(arguments.length); console.info(responseJSON); console.info(responseJSON.url); }` and check developer tools console output.

Comment: Yes, it's executed properly, but when I run alert(responseJSON['url']), in FF it shows /media/campaigns/20111118162942_home_cooking_win_01.png and in IE8/IE9 it shows undefined.

Comment: @Sergey Basharov. Try next code `onComplete:function(id, fileName, responseJSON) { for(var p in responseJSON)console.info(p,": ",responseJSON[p]); }` to check content of _responseJSON_ object in IE.

Comment: @SergeyBasharov Please add your "SOLVED" info into a separate answer and mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried playing with mimetype on server side. `application/json` made IE download the response as a file, and 'text/plain' made it surround response with `<pre></pre>`. Then I tried `text/html` and now response is evaluated properly so I can get values.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I experienced. Changing from application/json to text/html worked (even wrote a blog post about it: http://blog.degree.no/2012/09/jquery-json-ie8ie9-treats-response-as-downloadable-file/).